# Docker run WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I am using docker to run Nginx  through the Below command:

```
sudo docker run --network=host -p 8443:8443 --rm --name nginx-reverse -v $(pwd)/dhparam.pem:/etc/nginx/dhparam.pem:ro -v $(pwd)/full.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro  -v $(pwd)/cert.pem:/certs/cert.pem:ro -v $(pwd)/key.pem:/certs/key.pem:ro -d nginx:1.9.10
```

But getting the error Like:

```
WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode
ebb2cc854043438e57fdd551e1f667889add90c57f66c6015bfce93b2e5d1735
```

Because of this I am not able to run my container . why i am getting this can anyone please help me related this ?? why this is coming to me. I am a newbie in docker.Before it was working fine but now it is not working.
What issue am I getting. Its been up for 2 seconds. But after 2 seconds when I am doing docker ps and docker ps -a it is not showing me there. Why is this happening?

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. The warning comes because you use the `-p` option which doesn't make sense when you also have `--network=host`. Remove either `-p` or `--network` and the warning will go away.

Comment: If you use host network, you don't need to use -p option. All exposed ports will be automatically mapped to the host.

Comment: ...but using the host network is almost never necessary, and disables Docker's networking layer.  Remove the `--network=host` option.  (Or run the Nginx server directly on the host, if you don't want network isolation and you do want to serve host files.)

Comment: @HansKilian
  What issue am I getting. Its been up for 2 seconds. But after 2 seconds when I am doing docker ps and docker ps -a it is not showing me there. Why is this happening?